# jQuery animate border

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, border

Hi I am trying to animate the border of an input but no matter how I put the border it just doesn't seem to animate.

My current code:

`$(this).animate({border : '1px solid #f00'}, 'slow', 'linear');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the border color and style css properties
In full jquery :

```
$(this).css({borderColor:"#f00",borderStyle:"solid"}).animate({borderWidth : '3px'}, 'slow', 'linear');
```

You need plug-in for animate border color in jquery, check this :
http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Then..

```
$(this).animate({borderColor: '#f00'});
```

Maybe that's could help someone...

Answer (score 2):

You need to animate one parameter at a time.

```
border-width : '1px'
```

or

```
border-color : '#f00'
```

Comment: If he's not using jQuery UI I think it's probably worth mentioning that he'll need the [color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to animate the `border-color`.

Comment: It's not `border-width` it's `borderWidth` for anyone else using this

Comment: It's border-width is setting via CSS, it's borderWidth if setting via JavaScript.