# How i can show red border around text field for 3 second?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried this construction:

```
field.animate({border: '1px solid rgb(173, 26, 26)'}, 3000, function() {
    $(this).css('border', 'none');
});
```

but

```
border: '1px solid rgb(173, 26, 26)'
```

don't work.
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery animate border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883545/jquery-animate-border)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: As mentioned by @showdev, colors cannot be animated only using jQuery. You either need a plugin like jQuery UI, or to use CSS transitions.

You need to modify each property separately:

```js
$('div').animate({
                   borderWidth: '1px',
                   borderColor: 'rgb(173, 26, 26)'
                 }, 2000, function() {
                       $(this).css('border', 'none');
});
```

```css
div{
    border: 20px solid green;
    padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) only works on *numeric* CSS properties. "The [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) project extends the .animate() method by allowing some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated." See [jQuery UI Color Animation](https://jqueryui.com/animate/)

Comment: @showdev True! I forgot about that, as I don't use jQuery anymore, but css animations.

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    $('input').removeClass('red').css('border','none');
}, 3000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/y1aza1t5/1/)

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. Also, the `css()` call seems redundant.